# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'chars' was corrupted

Tags: c, visual-studio

```
char* putNum(Node* head)
{
    char* str;
    int size = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int lastNum, count = 0;

    Node* temp = head->left;
    lastNum = temp->info;
    while (lastNum != 0)
    {
        lastNum = lastNum / 10;
        count++;
    }

    if (head->info < 0)
    {
        size = abs(head->info) - 1;
        size *= 5 + count;
        str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
        str[0] = '-';
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        size = head->info - 1;
        size *= 5 + count;
        str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < abs(head->info); i++)
    {
        char chars[5];
        itoa(temp->info, chars, 10);
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(chars); j++)
        {
            str[index++] = chars[j];
        }
        temp = temp->left;
    }
    return str;
}
```

hi im learing c in visual studio and im tring to make a function that take a doubly linked list with a long number and put the number in a string. the error pops in the last '}' of the function.

Comment: What in case that `temp->info` is greather than 9999 or less than -999?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Use the debugger to single-step, set breakpoints, and look at the call stack and you should be able to track this down on your own.  That's a big part of learning to be a developer so it's better for you to fix this than for us to solve it for you.

Comment: the temp->info shouldnt be out of the range because i made that list that it will have only 5 digits in the info. and i tried to debugg it my self and couldnt find the problem thats why i came here

Comment: i have noticed that if i try to do it with the number 676671 it will put in the first time the 6 in the chars array and after that it will take the last 5 digits but then the chars array show in the locals tab "76671... and not "76671" . can this be a problem?

Comment: `chars` only has room for 4 characters, since one is needed for the terminating NUL.

Comment: `char chars[5];` should be large enough to contain the longest textual form for *any* number of that integer type. But you might be tempted to think that `char chars[11];` will be enough to hold `INT_MAX` plus the nul terminator, but `INT_MIN` needs one more for the minus sign. The lesson is *don't be mean/tight with your string lengths*: `char chars[20];` is not extravagant on a 8 or 16 Gb machine.

Comment: thank you that was the problem Weather Vane, i made the chars bigger and it solved the problem